# Avoiding memory leaks when storing OpenCV Mat objects in STL containers

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks

I'm using OpenCV and I want to store a number of images (`Mat` objects) in a vector. I have declared the vector as follows to store pointers to `Mat` objects.

```
std::vector<Mat*> images;
```

The `Mat` objects are created using the `new` keyword, and then added to the vector.

```
Mat *img = new Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3);
// set the values for the pixels here
images.push_back(img);
```

How would I go about making sure that I free the memory occupied by the `Mat` objects to avoid memory leaks?

What I'm doing right now is the following:

```
Mat *im = images.at(index);
// process and display image here
delete(im);
```

Valgrind is reporing a possible memory leak with reference to the created Mat objects. Am I missing something?

**Edit:**

Ok. Apparently it is better to avoid using `Mat` pointers and dynamically allocating `Mat` using `new`. I have modified my code to use `std::vector<Mat>` instead. However, I still see some blocks that were allocated by `Mat` possibly lost in the Valgrind report. I also notice that memory usage steadily increases while the program is running.

Let me clarify what I'm doing. I'm creating images in a function and placing them in a buffer (internally using a `std::deque`). This buffer is then accessed by another function to retrieve and image and pass it to another function which performs processing and rendering.

```
class Render {
   public:
      void setImage(Mat& img) {
         this->image = img;
      }

      void render() {
         // process image and render here
      }
   private:
      Mat image;
}
```

Thread that continuously fetches images from buffer and renders them.

```
void* process(void *opaque) {

   ImageProcessor *imgProc = (ImageProcessor*) opaque;
   Mat img;


   while (imgProc->isRunning) {
      // get an image from the buffer
      imgProc->buffer->getFront(img);

      // set the image
      imgProc->renderer->setImage(img);

      // process and render
      imgProc->renderer->render();
   }

}
```

Now, everything is passed as object references (i.e. `Mat&`). I assume that after getting an image from the buffer and passing it to the rendering function, the only reference to that object will be in that function. Therefore, when I get another image, there will no longer be a reference to that object and it will be destroyed. But Valgrind gives me the following:

```
25,952,564 bytes in 11 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 14,852 of 14,853
  in ImageProcessor::generateImage() in ImageProcessor.cpp:393
  1: malloc in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
  2: cv::fastMalloc(unsigned long) in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2
  3: cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int) in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2
  4: cv::Mat::create(int, int, int) in /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:353
  5: cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int) in /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:75
  ...
```

And here is `generateImage()`:

```
void generateImage() {
   Mat img(h, w, CV_8UC3); 
   // set values of pixels here
   this->buffer->pushBack(img);
}
```

Comment: The Mat class manages memory allocation and has reference counting so that `std::vector<Mat>` does the work for you and still only copies the pointer plus size information without unnecessary allocations and copies of the large Matrix content.

Comment: @mars I have updated the question with some parts of the code after updating it as you suggested. I still encounter a memory leak though and the problem still persists.

Comment: The parts of your code shown here should work. Can you elaborate a bit on that opaque pointer? Where does it come from, how does it get initialized, and who owns it and calls the destructor of the `ImageProcessor` when it is no longer needed? Note that `void * opaque=new ImageProcessor; do_stuff(opaque); free opaque;` calls the constructor of `ImageProcessor` but the destructor of `void`).

Comment: @mars The opaque pointer is basically a pointer to an `ImageProcessor` object. As I mentioned `process()` is a thread function. I create a thread using the **pthreads** library and pass a pointer to `process()` and a pointer to an object that is basically the parameter to the thread's function. This is how threads are created using `pthread_create()`. Here, I'm just passing a reference to `ImageProcessor` so that the thread can invoke its methods. When and where the destructor of `ImageProcessor` is called should not be a problem. Since I'm removing the `Mat` objects from the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a great use case for shared pointers.  The basic idea behind a smart pointer is that it behaves like a reference counted regular pointer.  When nothing else holds a reference to it, it automatically free-s itself.

The way you'd use them in your example would be

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Mat> > images;
std::shared_ptr<Mat> mat_ptr (new Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3));
images.push_back(mat_ptr);
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh279669.aspx)'s a handy tutorial for more about shared pointers.  If I misunderstood something about your question/problem, feel free to follow up below.

Answer (score 1):

If you are careful to actually delete the objects, then there are no memory leaks. That being said, there are ways to store pointers in vectors that are less prone to human errors (i.e. you forgetting to delete the objects in some corner case of your application).

If you can use C++11 then I'd recommend using `std::shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers. This will ensure that the memory is deleted (automatically) when there no longer is any code that uses your `Mat` object.

There's also the advantage that besides having to change the type of the pointer there aren't any other modifications you have to do. The usual `ptr->member` and `*ptr` expressions are valid for `std::shared_ptr` as well.

Here's some [documentation on `std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Also, depending on you specific needs, you might want to look into [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) as well.

---

Edit: Since C++11 is not an option, you could try [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) — the standard `std::shared_ptr` is based on the Boost one. If Boost is not an option either, you could implement your own shared pointer, it's not very hard.

The size of your program is something else to think about. If your application is fairly small and there's little chance for you to forget about some corner case that could cause memory leaks, all of this might be over-engineering. In case simply deleting the objects "by hand" will do then consider doing that.

Comment: Unfortunately, it may not be straight-forward to move to C++11. Is there a way to do this without using C++11? I mean, what would be the proper way for releasing the memory allocated by a `Mat` object that was created using the `new` keyword? I know that creating an object without `new` should release all resources when there aren't any reference to it. But I'm not sure about dynamically creating it using `new`.

Comment: If an object is created with `new` you must destroy it (at some point) by using `delete`. See my edit about what to consider as alternatives to C++11.

Comment: I have changed the code to avoid using pointers and allocating and deleting objects by hand. I edited the question to provide some more details. But apparently, I still get the face the same issue.